# Magento 2: Issue with PayPal Express checkout

Tags: magento2.3, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-express

I have integrated Paypal express checkout on my Magento 2 website. It's redirecting to PayPal after checkout. But when I'm login to the Paypal account I'm getting an error message.

We’re sorry. This seller doesn’t accept payments in your currency. Please return to the seller and choose another way to pay.

Although I have allowed all currency and primary currency is USD.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly check what type of currencies is you paypal account accepting [PayPal currency setup](https://www.paypal.com/sm/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-convert-my-paypal-balance-to-a-different-currency-faq532)
2. Secondly kindly provide us with PayPal request payload (without any sensitive data)

Either currency is not properly set in payload or your account do not accept the currency. Might be both.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/sm/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-convert-my-paypal-balance-to-a-different-currency-faq532
The page you're looking for is no longer available.

Comment: In the merchant account, USD is the primary currency. Other currency is AUD, INR, EUR , GBP, CAD, NZD. PayPal merchant account is Indian account.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&country.x=IN&locale.x=en_GB#/checkout/login

Comment: Customer paypal account is also Indian.